# Should all RxJS Subscription need to be unsubscribed?

Tags: rxjs

I have the following code in an angular component to capture the `keyup` events and respond when that happens. The user can navigate away from the page, come back and do the same hundreds of times.

```
    fromEvent(this.input?.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .pipe(
        pluck<unknown, string>('target', 'value'),
        filter((searchTerm: string) => (searchTerm?.length > 2 || searchTerm?.length == 0)),
        throttleTime(200),
        debounceTime(300),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe(search => {
        this.setPageIndex();
        this.TriggerLoadUsers(search, 'asc', 0, 10);
      });
```

This is another pattern where an explicit assignment of `Subscription` is done and then unsubscribed in `ngOnDestroy` of angular lifecycle method.

```
public keyupEventsSub$!: Subscription;

this.keyupEventsSub$ = fromEvent(this.input?.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .pipe(
        pluck<unknown, string>('target', 'value'),
        filter((searchTerm: string) => (searchTerm?.length > 2 || searchTerm?.length == 0)),
        throttleTime(200),
        debounceTime(300),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe(search => {
        this.setPageIndex();
        this.TriggerLoadUsers(search, 'asc', 0, 10);
      });

this.keyupEventsSub$.unsubscribe();
```

1. Is there an advantage to following the second pattern where a `Subscription` is explicitly assigned, `subscribed` and `unsubscribed`?
2. Is there any side effect in using the same pattern for any `Observable` subscription?
3. Is there a better pattern where an explicit assignment is not necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Yes, all subscriptions should be unsubscribed to prevent memory leaks. You don't have to unsubscribe from Http calls or Router events because they are one and done and Angular takes care of it for us but I personally still unsubscribe from all subscriptions.

2.) There is no side effect for using the same pattern for any observable subscription. There are many patterns and I will show at the end.

3.) There is a better pattern and I will go from least preferred to most preferred.

Direct subscription assignment. The disadvantage of this is that you will have many subscription variables for every observable stream so it may get out of hand.

```
// Direct subscription variable (What you have shown)
// don't put a dollar at the end of subscription variable because
// it is a subscription and not an observable
public subscription!: Subscription;
....
this.subscription = this.observable$.subscribe(...);
...
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Subscription array:
Add every subscription inside of an array.

```
public subscriptions!: Subscription[];
...
this.subscriptions.push(this.observable$.subscribe(...));
...
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.subscriptions.forEach(subscription => subscription.unsubscribe());
}
```

Async pipe:
One of my favorites but can only be used when presenting data in the HTML and not for event listener (in essence meaning react every time an observable emits).
When the view is presented, the observable will automatically be subscribed to and once the view is destroyed, the subscription is unsubscribed.

```
count$ = this.otherObservable$.pipe(map(data => data.count));
...
<h1>{{ count$ | async }}</h1>
```

Destruction subject:
Another one of my favorites and this one is good for subscriptions in the TypeScript class (for event listeners). The beauty of this one is that not too many variables are created and you don't have to deal with an array.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
....
private destructionSubject$ = new Subject<void>();
...
observable$.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destructionSubject$),
).subscribe(...);
observable2$.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destructionSubject$),
).subscribe(...);
...
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.destructionSubject$.next();
  this.destructionSubject$.complete();
}
```

There is also another way if all you care about is the first emission and not subsequent emissions:

This can be used for event listeners (react every time this observable emits). This will take the first emission and automatically unsubscribe (the subscription becomes dead).

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
....
observable$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(...);
```

I hope I answered all of your questions and presented you with good ways to unsubscribe.

Comment: Do you consider using ```tap``` as in the following code is another approach with the same benefits ```this.route.firstChild.paramMap.pipe(
  take(1),
  tap(map=>this.getRouteParams(map))
).subscribe();```?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the `take(1)` pattern as well. Yes, that `take(1)` approach is good if all you care about is the first emission.

Comment: One concept briefly mentioned in this answer is the "one and done" observables, but it involves a crucial point. Observables can send a "complete" signal in some situations. When using Angular's http service, it will return an observable with the response data and then will emit "complete'. This causes any subscribers to automatically unsubscribe.  The `take()` operator sends a "complete" event after it has received its count of emitted values. It is important to know that not all observables complete, so do your research and when in doubt always unsubscribe.

Answer (score 1):

## Should all RxJS Subscriptions be unsubscribed?

Only `Observables` that may never `error` or `complete` need to be unsubscribed. If you're not sure, it's safer to unsubscribe.

`from(promise)` is guaranteed to complete or error.
`from(['a','r','r','a','y'])` is guaranteed to complete.
`of(...)` is guaranteed to complete.
`EMPTY` is guaranteed to complete.
`NEVER` shall never complete or fail.
`fromEvent(...)` may never complete or fail.
`http.get(...)` a well written http client should always complete or fail eventually, but there are some (for various technical reasons) which don't. If you're not sure, unsubscribe.

## How to unsubscribe

In general, implicit is better than explicit. There are various operators that will unsubscribe for you when a certain condition is met.

`take`,
`takeWhile`, and
`takeUntil`

are the 3 most popular of these. Prefer them over sticking `stream.unsubscribe()` in our code somewhere.

Doing so keeps all the logic concerning your observable in one place. Making it considerably easier to maintain/extend as the number of observables that you use grows.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can experiment if we should explicitly unsubscribe from a subscription.
We can pass the `complete callback` as the third parameter in the `subscribe` method. If we see that the `complete callback` is called immediately after the `next callback` then we need not explicitly unsubscribe from that subscription. And at the end of our experiment, we can remove the `complete callback` if it was used just for the experimental purpose.
For example, here we can see that the `HttpClient.post` request completes after calling the next callback:

```
this.httpClient.post('https://httpbin.org/post', {testParam: 'testparam'}).subscribe(
  (response) => {
     console.log('got response', response);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log('error', error);
  },
  () => console.log('request/subscription completed')
);
```

I am not sure if it is a good approach, but seems to be a workable approach. Please correct me if I am wrong.
Thank you.